# Understanding the different ways of creating a NSCollectionLayoutGroup for a UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uikit

I'm attempting to create a very basic collection view layout using `UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout` that displays my collection view's cells as 3 squares lined up horizontally similar to the following:
[image]

But I'm having trouble understanding the difference between two ways of creating a `NSCollectionLayoutGroup`

The `NSCollectionLayoutItem` being used in the group is very simple and is defined as follows:

```
let tripletItem = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: NSCollectionLayoutSize(
     widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1),
     heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1))
)
```

In my mind, there are two different ways to create the `NSCollectionLayoutGroup` for this layout.

The first:

```
let tripletGroup = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: NSCollectionLayoutSize(
     widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1),
     heightDimension: .fractionalWidth(1/3)
), subitem: tripletItem, count: 3)
```

The second:

```
let tripletGroup = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: NSCollectionLayoutSize(
     widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1),
     heightDimension: .fractionalWidth(1/3)
), subitems: [tripletItem, tripletItem, tripletItem])
```

However, only the first option results in the desired layout. 
The second option results in a **single** item being stretched the full width of the view (imagine the first image with one long rectangle instead of three individual squares)

But I don't really understand the difference between these two methods and I feel they should result in the same layout

Am I missing something obvious here?